# hierarchy in react Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning react, and I try to create some routes, I have this code on my entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './app/Components/AppComponent';
import SupervisoryReport from './app/Components/SupervisoryReportComponent';
import Topmenu from './app/Components/TopmenuComponent';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={SupervisoryReport} />
            <Route path="test">
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

This works fine. What I need now is when I navigate to `/test` to still render the Supervisory report, and add some stuff. But apparently, it only renders what is inside the current route, and not upper routes.

Any idea how to do that?

**EDIT**

Here is more explain what I want to do:

Let's suppose I have a route `/supervisory-report` which have 20 pages inside like: `/supervisory-report/page-1`, `/supervisory-report/page-2`, etc

every one of that pages must have a component.

then I have some other routes, like '/test'.

Is there a way for all pages inside Supervisory Report, to show the same component, instead of rendering again in each component for each route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want every route to contain `SupervisoryReport` inside of `App`, you don't need to have this logic in your routing.  I think it would be better to modify your App component's render method:

```
return (
    <div>
        <SupervisoryReport>
            {this.props.children} // if you want the component to be inside
        </SupervisoryReport>
        {this.props.children} // if you want the component to be after
    </div>);
```

And then your routing can be simplified to:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="test" component={TestComponent} />
</Route>
```

I think it only makes sense to include `SupervisoryReport` in your route config if you plan on swapping it out when the route changes.  If this is the case, you can try something like:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="other" component={OtherComponent}/>
    <Route path="*" component={SupervisoryReport}>
        <Route path="test" component={TestComponent} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Note that you must have the * path last, as react will not check for any routes once it finds a match.

Edit: To solve your problem, I would try something like:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="test" component={TestComponent}/>
    <Route path="supervisory-report" component={SupervisoryReport}>
        <Route path="page-1" component={PageOneComponent}/>
        <!-- etc -->
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem from your code there is no component that is attached to the path "test". Your Route should be like this

```
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={SupervisoryReport} />
            <Route path="test" component={TestComponent}/>

        </Route>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but in that case, on `/test` in loads the `TestComponent` only, and not the SupervisoryReport

Comment: The SupervisoryReport is your IndexRoute which matches the path "/", who can you explain more on what you want to achieve.